# Kafka-topics.sh error with Failed to load SSL keystore /keystore.bcfks of type BCFKS / BCFKS not found / BCFKS KeyStore not available

Tags: apache-kafka, aws-msk

I am running kafka-topics.sh :9098 --describe --topic __consumer_offsets --command-config  /etc/client.properties

its throwing below error

```
Failed to create new KafkaAdminClient
org.apache.kafka.common.KafkaException: Failed to create new KafkaAdminClient
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.admin.KafkaAdminClient.createInternal(KafkaAdminClient.java:541)
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.admin.KafkaAdminClient.createInternal(KafkaAdminClient.java:492)
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.admin.Admin.create(Admin.java:137)
        at org.apache.kafka.tools.TopicCommand$TopicService.createAdminClient(TopicCommand.java:437)
        at org.apache.kafka.tools.TopicCommand$TopicService.<init>(TopicCommand.java:426)
        at org.apache.kafka.tools.TopicCommand.execute(TopicCommand.java:98)
        at org.apache.kafka.tools.TopicCommand.mainNoExit(TopicCommand.java:87)
        at org.apache.kafka.tools.TopicCommand.main(TopicCommand.java:82)
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.KafkaException: Failed to create new NetworkClient
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.ClientUtils.createNetworkClient(ClientUtils.java:252)
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.ClientUtils.createNetworkClient(ClientUtils.java:189)
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.admin.KafkaAdminClient.createInternal(KafkaAdminClient.java:525)
        ... 7 more
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.KafkaException: org.apache.kafka.common.KafkaException: Failed to load SSL keystore /etc/client/certs/keystore.bcfks of type BCFKS
        at org.apache.kafka.common.network.SaslChannelBuilder.configure(SaslChannelBuilder.java:184)
        at org.apache.kafka.common.network.ChannelBuilders.create(ChannelBuilders.java:192)
        at org.apache.kafka.common.network.ChannelBuilders.clientChannelBuilder(ChannelBuilders.java:81)
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.ClientUtils.createChannelBuilder(ClientUtils.java:119)
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.ClientUtils.createNetworkClient(ClientUtils.java:223)
        ... 9 more
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.KafkaException: Failed to load SSL keystore /etc/client/certs/keystore.bcfks of type BCFKS
        at org.apache.kafka.common.security.ssl.DefaultSslEngineFactory$FileBasedStore.load(DefaultSslEngineFactory.java:382)
        at org.apache.kafka.common.security.ssl.DefaultSslEngineFactory$FileBasedStore.<init>(DefaultSslEngineFactory.java:354)
        at org.apache.kafka.common.security.ssl.DefaultSslEngineFactory.createKeystore(DefaultSslEngineFactory.java:304)
        at org.apache.kafka.common.security.ssl.DefaultSslEngineFactory.configure(DefaultSslEngineFactory.java:164)
        at org.apache.kafka.common.security.ssl.SslFactory.instantiateSslEngineFactory(SslFactory.java:141)
        at org.apache.kafka.common.security.ssl.SslFactory.configure(SslFactory.java:98)
        at org.apache.kafka.common.network.SaslChannelBuilder.configure(SaslChannelBuilder.java:180)
        ... 13 more
Caused by: java.security.KeyStoreException: BCFKS not found
        at java.base/java.security.KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.java:878)
        at org.apache.kafka.common.security.ssl.DefaultSslEngineFactory$FileBasedStore.load(DefaultSslEngineFactory.java:376)
        ... 19 more
Caused by: java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: BCFKS KeyStore not available
        at java.base/sun.security.jca.GetInstance.getInstance(GetInstance.java:159)
        at java.base/java.security.Security.getImpl(Security.java:656)
        at java.base/java.security.KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.java:875)
        ... 20 more
```

my client.properties file contains

```
cat client.properties 
# Kafka client configuration
bootstrap.servers=xxxx.amazonaws.com
security.protocol=SASL_SSL
sasl.mechanism=AWS_MSK_IAM
sasl.jaas.config=software.amazon.msk.auth.iam.IAMLoginModule required;
sasl.client.callback.handler.class=software.amazon.msk.auth.iam.IAMClientCallbackHandler

# SSL configurations for BouncyCastle
ssl.truststore.type=BCFKS
ssl.truststore.location=/etc/client/certs/truststore.bcfks
ssl.truststore.password=<redacted>

ssl.keystore.type=BCFKS
ssl.keystore.location=/etc/client/certs/keystore.bcfks
ssl.keystore.password=<redacted>

# Configure the BouncyCastle provider
ssl.security.provider=BouncyCastleProvider
```

Also I have set java.security file as

```
cat java.security | grep security.provider
#    security.provider.<n>=<provName | className>
security.provider.1=org.bouncycastle.jcajce.provider.BouncyCastleFipsProvider
security.provider.2=org.bouncycastle.jsse.provider.BouncyCastleJsseProvider fips:BCFIPS
security.provider.3=SUN
security.provider.4=SunRsaSign
security.provider.5=SunEC
security.provider.6=SunJSSE
security.provider.7=SunJCE
security.provider.8=SunJGSS
security.provider.9=SunSASL
security.provider.10=XMLDSig
security.provider.11=SunPCSC
security.provider.12=JdkLDAP
security.provider.13=JdkSASL
security.provider.14=SunPKCS11
#   jdk.security.provider.preferred=AES/GCM/NoPadding:SunJCE, \
#jdk.security.provider.preferred=
login.configuration.provider=sun.security.provider.ConfigFile
policy.provider=sun.security.provider.PolicyFile
# provider (sun.security.provider.PolicyFile) does not support this property.
```

```
root@kafka-lag-dp-report-5254-7459f94c7d-xpjxl:/opt/java/openjdk/lib/security# cat java.security | grep fips             
security.provider.2=org.bouncycastle.jsse.provider.BouncyCastleJsseProvider fips:BCFIPS
fips.provider.1=org.bouncycastle.jcajce.provider.BouncyCastleFipsProvider
fips.provider.2=org.bouncycastle.jsse.provider.BouncyCastleJsseProvider fips:BCFIPS
```

scratching my head what else I am missing. Please help me identify the issue causing this error.